# Summary Report of Running JVMs

Tags: awk, grep, ps

Would like to output a summary of the currently running java processes. The fields I am interested in are PID, start time, min heap, max help and name of the app. The PID and start time are always at the same position so awk is working well for them. However, depending on the arguments used to start the JVM the min heap, which begins with -Xms and ends with m, the max heap, which begins with -Xmx and ends with m and the app name which can be gleaned from the field beginning with -Djboss.server.base end up in different positions so awk with position numbers is inconsistent. Here is what works for most of the processes. How can we improve this so it finds the min/max heap and app name where ever they are in the ps output?

```
ps -ef |grep "D\[S" |awk '{printf "%5s %5s %9s %9s %-35s\n",$2, $5, $(NF-16), $(NF-15), $(NF-2)}' | \
sed 's/-Djboss.server.base.dir=\/usr\/share\/jboss-as\///g' |  sed 's/-standalone//g' | \
sort -k5 | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l | sed -e '$s/$/ JBoss JVMs running/'
```

Expected output

```
715456 11:13  -Xms512m  -Xmx512m app1  
721978 13:08  -Xms512m  -Xmx512m app2  
722824 13:16  -Xms128m  -Xmx128m app3  
562899 Feb15  -Xms512m  -Xmx512m app4  
655796 Feb16 -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m app5  
5 JBoss JVMs running
```

However, for some apps the position of the heap size and and the -Djboss.server.base qualifiers are not at the specified positions. For those the output is incorrect. For example:

```
620378 Feb16 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman app6
```

Example of a running process.

```
jboss     653349  653268  0 Feb16 ?        00:00:39 java -D[Standalone] -server -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/usr/share/jboss-as/witr_standalone/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,com.sun.crypto.provider -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.modules.policy-permissions=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/share/jboss-as/witr_standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/share/jboss-as/witr_standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/share/jboss-as/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/share/jboss-as/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/share/jboss-as -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/share/jboss-as/witr_standalone -c standalone.xml
```

Expected output

```
653349 Feb16 -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m witr
```

Comment: Seem like you could use sed with regex and capture groups?

Comment: How would we use sed to capture the groups? The min heap starts with -Xms and ends with m after some digits, the max heaps starts with -Xmx and ends with m after some digits and the last field we want starts with -Djboss.server.base.dir and ends with _standalone.

Comment: Not sure how it could but hopefully that 1 sample input line you provided covers all of the use cases you need to handle as that's all we have to test with. If it doesn't then please [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input and the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU sed for `-E` to enable EREs and `\s/\S` shorthand for `[[:space:]]/[^[:space:]]`:

```
$ cat file | sed -E 's:\S+\s+(\S+)(\s+\S+){2}\s+(\S+).*(-Xms[0-9]+m).*(-Xmx[0-9]+m).*-Djboss\.server\.base\.dir[^ ]+/([^ ]+)_standalone.*:\1 \3 \4 \5 \6:'
653349 Feb16 -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m witr
```

Obviously in the above I'm using `cat file` instead of `ps -ef` just for testing with the sample input you provided:

```
$ cat file
jboss     653349  653268  0 Feb16 ?        00:00:39 java -D[Standalone] -server -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/usr/share/jboss-as/witr_standalone/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,com.sun.crypto.provider -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.modules.policy-permissions=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/share/jboss-as/witr_standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/share/jboss-as/witr_standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/share/jboss-as/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/share/jboss-as/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/share/jboss-as -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/share/jboss-as/witr_standalone -c standalone.xml
```